# curly brackets inside command substitution which is assigned to variable in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

What is the purpose of curly brackets inside command substitution which is assigned to variable in bash e.g.

```
VAR=$({})
```

There is code where I saw this construction:

```
#!/bin/bash
test $# -ge 1 || { echo "usage: $0 write-size [wait-time]"; exit 1; }
test $# -ge 2 || set -- "$@" 1
bytes_written=$(
{
    exec 3>&1
    {
        perl -e '
            $size = $ARGV[0];
            $block = q(a) x $size;
            $num_written = 0;
            sub report { print STDERR $num_written * $size, qq(\n); }
            report; while (defined syswrite STDOUT, $block) {
                $num_written++; report;
            }
        ' "$1" 2>&3
    } | (sleep "$2"; exec 0<&-);
} | tail -1
)
printf "write size: %10d; bytes successfully before error: %d\n" \
    "$1" "$bytes_written"
```

Taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are used to group multiple commands in a script. They have the same meaning inside a command substitution as they do at top-level.

They're like wrapping the commands in parentheses, except that curly braces don't create a subshell, while parentheses do (this matters if the commands do things like variable assignments or `cd`). Also, unlike parentheses, curly braces are not self-delimiting, so you need to have whitepace after the `{` and a command delimiter (e.g. `;` or newline) before the `}`.

This is documented in the Bash manual section on [Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)

Comment: echo $$ vs ( echo $$ ) returns same PID so where is sub-shell you've mentioned?

Comment: `foo=1; (foo=2); echo $foo` echoes `1`, not `2`.

Comment: But `foo=1; { foo=2 ;}; echo $foo` echoes `2`

Comment: Added a link to the documentation.

Comment: I see, thanks. And what is the benefit of grouping multiple commands?

Comment: It allows you to redirect or pipe the output of a group of commands. Also, it can be used to override the precedence of operators, as on the first line of your script.

Comment: Thank you very much, may I last question, what operator precedence is overrided in my example?

Comment: If you didn't have the curly braces, `exit 1` would be executed regardless of the result of `test $# -eq 1`, because `;` has lower precedence than `||`.

Comment: @WakanTanka `BASHPID` is what you need to have the PID of subshell: `echo "$$ - $BASHPID"; ( echo "$$ - $BASHPID" )`.

Comment: @WakanTanka And from the documentation of `$$`: _In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the
              subshell._

Comment: Almost everything you need to know is in the manual, if you just make the effort to look.